# C# Web Page. Trouble using button click to update textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

So I'm creating a dummy webpage for basics right now. The Goal:
On a button click, I want to update information shown in the textbox.

The method myButton_Click takes in the parameters of the button. How can I access an object like textbox (or any object for that matter) since it is not being accessed from a buttonclick event? I set up a public variable, `myTextBox_`,  which I think I could then edit freely. But I'm still not sure how to set `myTextBox_` to understand that it is connected to the webpage.

Html:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <p style="height: 324px">
        <asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" EnableTheming="True" Text="Button" onclick="myButton_Click"/>

        <asp:TextBox ID="myTextBox" runat="server">Hello</asp:TextBox>
    </p>
</form>
```

Then the C# Code:

```
Textbox myTextBox_;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//possibly initialization code set myTextBox_ to the id myTextbox, but how?
}

protected void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myTextbox_.text = "goodbye";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're very close. All you need to do is:

```
protected void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myTextBox.Text = "goodbye";
}
```

You don't need to set up anything in the `Page_Load` method, as you have them set up as `runatserver`, so they are accessible from the code behind.

As already stated, this will require a postback to work, to avoid this use AJAX or do it in pure JavaScript.

Comment: What about a table? if I have a table, i can't directly access myTable through this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn web on .NET, you should start learning ASP.NET MVC, not web pages.

Anyhow, I believe you don't get the same behaviour as in a desktop app, because when you click the button, you get a page postback (whole page is refreshed). You should use the page's postback event to change the text, not the button.

Or you should use the old "UpdatePanel" from ASP.NET Ajax 1.0, to put the button and the textbox in the same UpdatePanel (but you must first install that ASP.NET Ajax 1.0)

But pls, start using MVC :)
http://www.asp.net/mvc